# nosetests: multiple runs with different global configuration

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have a python library that reads a config file or environment variables to set some global configuration variables.

I would like to run my test suite multiple times with different settings.
I could do this manually like

> MYLIB_SETTINGS=enable_foo=True nosetests
>      MYLIB_SETTINGS=enable_foo=False nosetests

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this automatically using the nose api and combine the results.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would run your test in some sort of Continuous Integration framework (like Jenkins) with `--with-xunit` and `--xunit-file TEST_NAME_XXX.xml`. Each test run will produce a separate xml file, and the CI tool will combine them together into a pretty table, showing all tests from both cases.

You can do something similar using nose API, by setting `os.env` variables appropriately in python and calling [nose.run()](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#basic-usage)